# can't acess public static member of one class from another class

Tags: c#, global-variables

I am writing windows forms application which needs to have global variable to change from one Form class and then to be used from another Form class

this is class for global variables

```
namespace Testi
{
    public class publicVar
    {
       public static int kitxvisN = 0;
       public static int sworipas = 0;
    }
}
```

and this is class where I want to use it

```
namespace Testi
{   
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        publicVar something = new publicVar();
        something.kitxvisN++;
        ....
```

but it says invalid token ++ . . . 
what is wrong can somebody help me?

Comment: try `publicVar.kitxvisN++`

Comment: tried this, not working.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to access `static` member as if it was not `static`. You don't need, and even can't use class instance to access `static` members. Use class name instead:

```
publicVar.kitxvisN++;
```

> Because there is no instance variable, you access the members of a
>   static class by using the class name itself.
>
> from [*Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

**Update**

Other thing is, you can't use code like that directly on class level. You need some method to put it inside it.

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    publicVar.kitxvisN++;
}
```

Comment: @MohammadYaseen Yes, I see where is the problem. He's trying to put the code directly on class level. It can't work. However, the `static` member accessed as if it was an instance one is a problem too.

Answer (score 0):

static members can't be used with objects. They can be accessed by class name such as publicVar.kitxvisN ++;

Answer (score 0):

Simply try with:

```
publicVar.kitxvisN++;
```

Because it's a `static` member and which does not require an instance to access that. `static` member should simply be accessed by class name itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't place those methods directly under class declaration. It has to be inside of a method. E.g.

```
namespace Testi
{   
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

         public static void Main(string[] args) {
              publicVar.kitxvisN++;
         }
```